# Finding all the shortest paths between two nodes in unweighted directed graphs using BFS algorithm

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search, shortest

I am working on a problem that I need to find all the shortest path between two nodes in a given directed unweighted graph. I have used BFS algorithm to do the job, but unfortunately I can only print one shortest path not all of them, for example if they are 4 paths having lenght 3, my algorithm only prints the first one but I would like it to print all the four shortest paths. I was wondering in the following code, how should I change it so that all the shortest paths between two nodes could be printed out?

```
class graphNode{
    public:
        int id;
        string name;
        bool status;
        double weight;
};


map<int, map<int,graphNode>* > graph; 


int Graph::BFS(graphNode &v, graphNode &w){

    queue <int> q;
    map <int, int> map1;  // this is to check if the node has been visited or not.
    std::string str= "";
    map<int,int> inQ;  // just to check that we do not insert the same iterm twice in the queue


    map <int, map<int, graphNode>* >::iterator pos;
    pos = graph.find(v.id);
    if(pos == graph.end()) {
        cout << v.id << " does not exists in the graph " <<endl;
        return 1;

    }

    int parents[graph.size()+1];   // this vector keeps track of the parents for the node
    parents[v.id] = -1;


    if (findDirectEdge(v.id,w.id) == 1 ){
        cout << " Shortest Path: " << v.id << " -> " << w.id << endl;
        return 1;
    } //if
    else{
        int gn;
        map <int, map<int, graphNode>* >::iterator pos;

        q.push(v.id);
        inQ.insert(make_pair(v.id, v.id));

        while (!q.empty()){
        gn = q.front();
        q.pop();
        map<int, int>::iterator it;
        cout << " Popping: " << gn <<endl;
        map1.insert(make_pair(gn,gn));


        if (gn == w.id){//backtracing to  print all the nodes if gn is the same as our target node such as w.id
            int current = w.id;
            cout << current << " - > ";
            while (current!=v.id){
                current = parents[current];
                cout << current << " -> ";
            }
        cout <<endl;
        }
                          if ((pos = graph.find(gn)) == graph.end()) {
            cout << " pos is empty " <<endl;
            continue;
        }
        map<int, graphNode>* pn = pos->second;

                          map<int, graphNode>::iterator p = pn->begin();
        while(p != pn->end()) {
            map<int, int>::iterator it;

            it = map1.find(p->first);//map1 keeps track of the visited nodes
            graphNode gn1= p->second;
            if (it== map1.end())    {
                map<int, int>::iterator it1;
                it1 = inQ.find(p->first);  //if the node already exits in the inQ, we do not insert it twice

                if (it1== inQ.end()){
                    parents[p->first] = gn;
                    cout << " inserting " << p->first << " into the queue " <<endl;
                    q.push(p->first);  // add it to the queue
                } //if
            }  //if
            p++;
          } //while

    } //while
}
```

I do appreciate all your great help
Thanks,
Andra

Answer (score 2):

1. `map<int, map<int,graphNode>* > graph` declares a graph with one `graphNode` object per edge.

   One `graphNode` per node would have type `map<int, map<int,graphNode*> >` or, even better, `map<graphNode*, set /* or vector */<graphNode*> >`, or perhaps better yet, `multimap< graphNode *, graphNode * >`.

   The `graphNode`s need to be stored in a separate structure (say, `vector` or `deque`) from whatever `map` you use.
2. `int parents[graph.size()+1];` is nonstandard. Use `vector<int> parents( graph.size()+1 );` instead.
3. To answer your question, you want to continue the BFS until you reach the first node of topological order greater than the first result. Introduce a variable `int first_id_of_next_level = v.id;`. (Or better, use a pointer.) When you find a match, append its path to a list of paths. When `gn == first_id_of_next_level`, either `return` the list if it is not `empty` or set `first_id_of_next_level = p->first`, the first child of the current parent, so you know the next opportunity to stop the search.

Comment: Your algorithm is correct but incorrectly worded, it is easily confused with topological sorting which has nothing to do with shortest paths.

Answer (score 1):

To write all of the shortest paths, you would have to write a recursive DFS-like algorithm.  Run a BFS to find the minimum distance to each node, store that, and then run a DFS from the source node, only branching to nodes which satisfy the minimum path.  Whenever you reach the target node, write the path you took to get there (which you have been keeping track of in your recursive function).  Note that you will not be marking nodes in your DFS.

Since the algorithm requires backtracking, the best way to do it is via recursive DFS.  You *could* write it with a BFS, but you would have to maintain a stack to keep track of your backtracking, which means you are essentially writing DFS with a manually maintained stack, i.e. writing the exact same algorithm with twice as much code as you need to.

Please be aware that the number of shortest paths is not always polynomial so you might be writing an exponential number of paths.

Comment: There is O(E) algorithm instead of exponential one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144071/finding-all-the-shortest-paths-between-two-nodes-in-unweighted-undirected-graph

Comment: @bitec No there isn't. How can there be a linear algorithm to write an exponential number of items? Think before you talk.

Comment: sorry, I'm wrong. I mean that the algorithm that uses edited BFS takes O(E) to prepare paths, and then it can be exponential to print them. But what I mean - in your variant after the minimal distance (M) is found you suggest to use modified DFS to find all paths (the one, that does not mark nodes as visited forever but only on recursion cycle) and finish the recursion whenever path exceeds M. This may results in exponential work even if there are only several shortest paths. That what I mean