# A* (A Star) Algorithm outputting all possible solutions

Tags: java, algorithm, a-star

The A star algorithm is known to be complete. However, all the implementations that I have found searching the web seem to only return only the first (optimal) solution.

For example, this implementation: 
[A star algoritthm implementation](http://code.google.com/p/a-star/source/browse/trunk/java/AStar.java)

Since the algorithm always expands the node with the minimum f value, and the implementations seem to stop when the first node is a solution, how would one adapt the aforementioned code so as to output all (or the first *n*) paths that lead to a goal, without taking into account duplicate actions (that is, paths that contain the same action over and over again)?

Comment: Simply do not stop after you found less than `n` solutions and you will get the `n` best solutions.

Comment: Surely that will not work?

Comment: @flup: Why? The search space is a tree, the A*-algorithm guarantees to find one optimal solution, if you cut this solution from the tree, the A*-algorithm will find one optimal solution for the reduced tree. You do not need to start the search again, because the calculations for each node of the tree have not changed.

Comment: @MrSmith42 Finding the optimal solution lies very much at the core of the algorithm. The nodes in the closed set all know only the optimal way to get there. Do you wish to cut all nodes that are on the optimal path from the tree?

Comment: @flup: The Question does not say that solutions are not allowed to have a partial common path. Cutting the found solution leaf would be enough to lead A* to one next optimal leaf.

Comment: @MrSmith42 Speaking in terms of [the wikipedia description of astar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), the value of the `came_from` arrows in the closed set that point at the optimal way to reach them will be pointless. The entire internal data structure is attuned to the optimal solution you just found. I really do not see how you could keep going or skip one solution.

Comment: @MrSmith42 Indeed, having a partial common path is a desired feature. My thought was exactly yours, not stopping after I have found one solution. However, as flup says, I 'm not sure it will actually work. Or if it does, if it will return the paths from minimum to maximum cost in that order.

Comment: @flup: As you see in the graphical example (wikipedia) when a search path leads to a blind end (or an other path seams cheaper) the next promising (in terms of cost) path will be searched. If you declare the already found best solution to a 'blind end' by cutting the leaf it is as if the solution never existed.

Comment: Assuming you count two different paths with the same length as "different," you can just do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144071/finding-all-the-shortest-paths-between-two-nodes-in-unweighted-undirected-graph/14145716#14145716) to find all paths of the shortest length, and if that doesn't give you enough paths, continue A* to find all paths of the next shortest length, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's complete which means it will find a solution if one exists, but the algorithm specifically only returns one path. A breadth-first search will find all non-cyclical paths between two nodes, however: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

**Update** - Here is the k-shortest paths algorithm which will return a list of n (or in this case, k) shortest paths in order of shortest to longest. http://code.google.com/p/k-shortest-paths/

Comment: This has in most cases much much worse performance than A`search.

Comment: A* is faster, but it doesn't do what he wants. If you make it do what he wants, it's going to be slower because it will no longer be looking for a single path, but all paths.

Comment: Search all path is exactly what breadth first search does. I do not know where your wisdom about the behavior of all possible modifications of A* comes. but I doubt it.

Comment: The poster asked for "how would one adapt the aforementioned code so as to output all (or the first n) paths that lead to a goal." How do you think A* can accomplish that? It doesn't do either of those things.

Answer (score 1):

For all paths, it probably makes a lot more sense to use breath first search. Alternatively, you can try [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) if you want to find the top n shortest paths.