# Find center of a sparse graph

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

I'm currently working on the following problem: Given a directed graph *G* = (*V*, *E*) I use Dijkstra's Algorithm to find the shortest distance *d<sub>i</sub>* for each node *v<sub>i</sub>* ∈ *V* from a startnode *v*<sub>0</sub>.

Now I want to find the node *v** for which the sum of all nodes shortest distances ∑*d<sub>i</sub>* from this node is minimized.

In the following example the startnode *v*<sub>0</sub> is yellow and obviously has the distance 0. The shortest distances for all other nodes are given.

[image: Figure 1]

In the first figure (startnode in the bottom left) the sum of all shortest distances is

∑*d<sub>i</sub>* = 1+2+2+2+3+3+3 = 16

[image: Figure 2]

In the second figure (startnode in the middle) the sum of all shortest distances is

∑*d<sub>i</sub>* = 1+1+1+2+2+2+2 = 11

The edge-weights are floats, in the example they are chosen to be 1 for the sake of simplicity.

Obiously I could try for every node to find the minimum but that of course is way too slow. I can't wait to hear your ideas! :-)

Comment: Are your edge weights always 1?

Comment: No. I just chose 1 for the example to be simple.

Comment: After some more research I found [_Edmonds' algorithm_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds'_algorithm). Is this a step towards the solution to my problem?

Comment: That could work, but you would still have to run it for each node. I'm not sure if there's something better since you only care about the cost and not the actual tree.

Comment: You are right. This isn't better than running *Dijkstra's algorithm* for each node.

Comment: I'm actually doing this on a road-graph so that _Floyd-Warshall algorithm_ is simply not feasible due to it's memory comsumption of O(|V|²).

Comment: I think the problem is related to [this one](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/79198/minimum-sum-of-distances-of-g-for-spanning-tree-of-g).

Comment: @user2033412 If you cannot afford |V|^2 memory, then is your graph sparse? If not, how do you want to avoid |V|^2 memory?

Comment: Yes. It is a road-graph, hence sparse.

Comment: @user2033412 Please define what do you mean by a road-graph. You're clearly looking for an algorithm to compute the center of a graph and there are linear algorithms for some graph classes (not only for a tree)

Comment: The graph is a road-network (openstreetmap-data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of social networks, the centrality metrics that you describe was defined by Sadibussi in 1966 (see [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02289527) or in an unofficial link [here](http://hbanaszak.mjr.uw.edu.pl/TempTxt/PDF/Sabidussi_1966_CentralityIndexOfAGraph.pdf) It is also described and recommended by Freeman [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.227.9549) (p.225) as a measure of decentrality). It is sometimes called farness (see [here](http://toreopsahl.com/tnet/weighted-networks/node-centrality/)).

Breadth-ﬁrst search allows one to calculate the lengths of the shortest paths from every vertex on a graph to every other. See the accepted answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144071/finding-all-the-shortest-paths-between-two-nodes-in-unweighted-undirected-graph) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58198/all-pairs-shortest-path-in-undirected-and-unweighted-graphs). Other methods for calculating All-Pairs Shortest Paths are described [here](http://www.cse.ust.hk/~dekai/271/notes/L13/L13.pdf).

**Edit:**

Since you noted that you are interested in an aproximate solution, have a look at the [following paper](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/sbaswana/Papers-published/journal-focs06.pdf) by Baswana and Kavitha. Table 1.1 summerizes known results. The best approximate solutions to date requires O(n^(3/2)) space for 3-stretch solution (which means that the estimated distance would be more than the real distance, but less than 3 times the real distance). I guess this is not good enough for most practical purposes. There are no known APASP (All-Pairs Approximate Shortest Paths) algorithms with stretch<3 and less than O(n^2) space requirements.

**Practical solutions:**

Most implementations exploits the hierarchy inherent in real world road networks. See for example [this](http://www.siam.org/proceedings/alenex/2007/alx07_004knopp.pdf), [this](http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/schultes/hwy/esaHwyHierarchies.pdf) and [this](http://algo2.iti.uka.de/schultes/hwy/).

Comment: I can't use APSP, because of it's memory consumption O(|V|²). The Graph has approximately 250000 nodes. Is there any approximation or other solution?

Comment: Thanks for your edit -- I guess I'll have give it a try with one of the APASP approaches where I don't have to store |V|² distance values but can query them when needed in short time.