# How to find all shortest paths

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, breadth-first-search, shortest-path

I have a graph and I want to find all shortest paths between two nodes. I've found a shortest path between two nodes by BFS. However, it just gives me one of the shortest paths if there exists one more than.

How could I get all of them using BFS?

I've implement my code from well-known BFS pseudocode.
Also, I have a adjacency list vector which holds adjacency vertices for all nodes.

Comment: @Dukeling thanks for reply. I dont want to find all paths between all vertices. What I want to find is all shortest paths between 2 specific  nodes.

Comment: You should post your actual code, not pseudocode.

Comment: @RetiredNinja since its kind an assignment,I should not put it here..

Comment: This is something similar to dp,assume the shortest distance is x, starting from start node, you go to every neighbor node that has the distance to target is x -1, and continue recursively. Done!

Comment: You can use dfs to find all paths from A to B. Sort the paths based on lengths, then you can find all shortest paths.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding all the shortest paths between two nodes in unweighted undirected graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144071/finding-all-the-shortest-paths-between-two-nodes-in-unweighted-undirected-graph)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way is to find all paths from source to destination using dfs. Now find the shortest paths among these paths. Here is a sudo code:

```
dfs(p,len)
      if(visited[p])
         return

      if(p== destination)
          paths.append(len)

          return
      visited[p]=1
      for each w adjacent to p
           dfs(w,len+1)
      visited[p]=0
```

You can find the path by maintaining an array for paths. I will leave that to you as an assignment

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong, you can not use dfs to find all paths from source to target. For example you will miss one of the two cases: 1->2->3->4 and 1->3->4. If you want to find "all" path, a recursive will be required, not dfs.

Comment: By the way,this quesion is duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144071/finding-all-the-shortest-paths-between-two-nodes-in-unweighted-undirected-graph?rq=1

Comment: Note that this is a very inefficient way of doing things. Consider a graph with a billion nodes and the shortest path between the two target nodes is of length 5. You'll be exploring all the nodes rather than just those distance 5 from the source node. [Modified BFS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144071/finding-all-the-shortest-paths-between-two-nodes-in-unweighted-undirected-graph?rq=1) is a lot better.

Comment: @PhamTrung DFS is recursive. For the `1` node, it will first go to `2`, and find `1->2->3->4` and then it will backtrack back to `1` and go to `3` and find `1->3->4`. And you duplicate comment would probably have been better suited as a comment on the *question* or a duplicate flag (I just flagged it).

Comment: @Dukeling, What i mean is complete search by recursive :) sorry, this code is not dfs, i misunderstood it :D and storing path in array is not a good idea as the path can already contain  the current node, which need a further check

Answer (score 19):

You can easily do it by maintaining a list or vector of parents for each node.
If two or more nodes ( say X, Y, Z) at the same distance from the starting node , leads to another node M , make all X , Y and Z as the parents of M.

You just have to add a check to see while adding a parent to the node whether that parent is in the same level as the previous parents.

By level , I mean the distance from the starting point.

This way you can get all the shortest paths by tracing back the parent vectors.
Below is my C++ implementation.

I hope you know how to print the paths by starting from the destination ,tracing the parents and reach the starting point.

**EDIT : Pseudo Code**

```
bfs (start , end)

    enqueue(start)
    visited[start] = 1

    while queue is NOT empty

        currentNode = queue.front()
        dequeue()

        if(currentNode == end)
            break

        for each node adjacent to currentNode

            if node is unvisited
                visited[node] = visited[curr] + 1
                enqueue(node)
                parent[node].add(currentNode)

            else if(currentNode is in same level as node's parents)
                parent[node].add(currentNode)

return
```

Comment: thanks to you, I got parents information correctly,however,I have no idea how could I print path by backtracing without recursion, do you have any hint ?

Comment: yes, you can use a stack and do it iteratively. I will post the pseudocode shortly.

Comment: The answer posted by banarun will work for printing all the paths.

Use the parent vectors instead of the adjacency list. Start from the destination and trace all the paths to the starting node.

Answer (score 9):

If the graph is large, finding all paths from start to end and then selecting the shortest ones can be very inefficient.  Here is a better algorithm:

1. Using BFS, label each node with its distance from the start node.  Stop when you get to the end node.

```py
def bfs_label(start, end):
    depth = {start: 0}
    nodes = [start]
    while nodes:
        next_nodes = []
        for node in nodes:
            if node == end:
                return depth

            for neighbor in neighbors(node):
                if neighbor not in depth:
                    depth[neighbor] = depth[node] + 1
                    fringe.append(neighbor)
```

2. Using DFS, find all paths from the start node to the end node such that the depth strictly increases for each step of the path.

```py
def shortest_paths(node, end, depth, path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = []

    path.append(node)

    if node == end:
        yield tuple(path)
    else:
        for neighbor in neighbors(node):
            if neighbor in depth and depth[neighbor] == depth[node]+1:
                for sp in shortest_paths(neighbor, end, depth, path):
                    yield sp

    path.pop()
```

Comment: Thanks! An equivalent way for step 2) would be find all paths from the end node to the start node such that the depth strictly decreases for each step of the path, right?

Answer (score -2):

We can use a simple BFS algorithm for finding all the shortest paths. We can maintain the path along with the current node. I have provided the link to the python code for the same below.
https://gist.github.com/mridul111998/c24fbdb46492b57f7f17decd8802eac2