# Returning all shortest paths in lowest run time and complexity

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257227/how-to-find-all-shortest-paths) has is the result that constantly appears for this problem but doesn't provide an optimal solution.

Currently I am trying to return all shortest paths starting at`from` and ending at `target` using BFS but I am running into a bottleneck with either my algorithm or the data structures I use.

pseudocode:

```
// The graph is an adjacency list of type unordered_map<string, unordered_set<string>>
// deque with pair of (visited unordered_set, vector with current path)
deque q = [({from}, [from]);

while q:
  pair = q.dequeue()
  visited = pair.first
  path = pair.second
  
  foreach adjacent_node to path[-1] in the graph:
    if (adjacent_node == target):
      res.append(path + [adjacent_node])
    
    else if adjacent_node not in visited:
      newPath = path + [adjacent_node]
      visited.add(adjacent_node)
      q.push((visited, newPath))
```

Currently the bottleneck seems to be with the queue's pair of items. I'm unsure how to solve the problem without storing a visited set with every path, or without copying a new path into the queue.

Comment: Please explain the nature of this "bottleneck".  And why have you tagged the question `c++` if you aren't going to post c++ code?

Comment: how do you know that the linked solution is not optimal? Maybe it is obvious but I don't see it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding all the shortest paths between two nodes in unweighted undirected graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144071/finding-all-the-shortest-paths-between-two-nodes-in-unweighted-undirected-graph)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you should know that number of shortest paths can be huge and returning them all is not practical. Consider a graph with `2k+1` layers numbered from `1` to `2k+1`, in which each layer is fully connected with the next layer, and odd layers has only one point while even layers has q points. Although this graph only has `k(q+1)+1` nodes and `kq` edges, there are in total `q^k` different shortest paths which can be inefficient for normal computers to handle. However if you're sure that the number of shortest paths is relatively small I can introduce the following algorithm.

The basic idea is to store a list `back` for each node, meaning the shortest distance between `from` and `x` equals to the shortest distance between `from` and `v` plus one if and only if `v in back[x]`. `back[x]` can be computed during the process. Then you can perform a depth-first search to print all the shortest path. Pseudo code (BTW I noticed that your code is not correct):

```
queue q = [ from ]

visited = set<node>
back = map<node, list<node>>

while q.not_empty():
  now = q.front()
  if (now == target):
    continue
  foreach adjacent_node to now in the graph:
    if (adjacent_node in visited):
      back[adjacent_node].push(now)
    else:
      visited.add(adjacent_node)
      back[adjacent_node] = [ now ]
      q.push(adjacent_node)

# Now collect all shortest paths

ret = []
current = []

def collect(x):
  current.push(x)
  if (x == from):
    ret.push(current.reversed())
    return
  foreach v in back[x]:
    collect(v)
  current.pop()
```

Sorry for my poor English. Feel free to point out my typos and mistakes.