# How to find all the shortest paths between two given vertices in an undirected graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph

The graph G is an undirected graph, and all its edges' weight are same. u,v are 2 given vertices, how to find the number of the shortest paths between u and v in graph G in O(|V|)?

|V| stands for the number of vertices in G.

Comment: I don't think it can be done. `O(|V|)` is way too strict. BFS (which I assume is the base for answer) takes `O(|E|+|V|)`, and you need O(|E| + |V|) to even read the graph properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding all the shortest paths between two nodes in unweighted undirected graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144071/finding-all-the-shortest-paths-between-two-nodes-in-unweighted-undirected-graph)

Comment: @AerofoilKite The linked question asked to *find* all shortest paths. This one asks only to *count* them. It's much easier task.

Comment: @amit, Idea is same.. You have to do the same job except storing visited node

Comment: @AerofoilKite No, it isn't - it is much easier to count the paths than to generate them. Counting them can take polynomial time, while generating them - cannot. I do agree you can solve this problem by generating all paths and counting them - but it's an overkill.

Comment: I think it is not possible to solve in `O(|V|)` time. Lets say there are 2 vertices connected with N edges . How to solve in constant time without checking for each edge E?

Answer (score 5):

You can use counting variation of BFS.

The idea is to hold a dictionary that maps `dict:(v,depth)->#paths` (entry is vertex and current depth and value is number of paths from source to this vertex with the desired depth).

At each iteration of the BFS, you track of the current depth of the path, and add the number of found paths to the next level.

The idea that if you have 3 paths leading to `x` and 4 paths leading to `y`, both on depth 3, and both have edge `(x,u),(y,u)` - then there are 7 paths leading to `u` - the 3 leading to `x`+(x,u), and the 4 leading to `y`+(y,u).

Should look something like that:

```
findNumPaths(s,t):
   dict = {} //empty dictionary
   dict[(s,0)] = 1 //empty path
   queue <- new Queue()
   queue.add((s,0))
   lastDepth = -1
   while (!queue.isEmpty())
       (v,depth) = queue.pop()
       if depth > lastDepth && (t,lastDepth) is in dict: //found all shortest paths
            break
       for each edge (v,u):
           if (u,depth+1) is not entry in dict:
               dict[(u,depth+1)] = 0
               queue.push((u,depth+1)) //add u with depth+1 only once, no need for more!
           dict[(u,depth+1)] = dict[(u,depth+1)] + dict[v,depth]

       lastDepth = depth
   return dic[t]
```

Run time is O(V+E) if using hash table for dictionary.

---

Another solution (easier to program but less efficient) is:

```
 1. Build the adjacency  matrix of the graph, let it be `A`. 
 2. Set `Curr = I` (identity matrix)
 3. while Curr[s][t] != 0:
    3.1. Calculate Curr = Curr * A //matrix multiplication
 4. Return Curr[s][t]
```

The reason it works is `(A^n)[x][y]` is the number of paths of size `n` in the graph `A` represents from `x` to `y`. We find the first number that is higher than zero, and return the number of paths.

Comment: The second solution is clever but the run time cannot be O(V+E).

Comment: @Gary33 No, the second solution is less efficient - but it's elegant, nice and extremely easy to program in Matlab, so I decided to add it as well. The first one should meet your complexity requirements, but is a bit more difficult to program.