# Breadth First Search Counter Example

Tags: graph-theory

Statement:

"Consider an arbitrary graph G=(V,E) and a source vertex s that is in V.  For each shortest paths tree rooted at s, there exists an ordering of the vertices in an adjacency list representation of G which results in precisely this shortest-paths tree when BFS is run from s."

I am struggling to come up with a counter-example for this statement that I have taken for face value to be FALSE.

I understand that the ordering matters when it comes to the shortest-paths tree derived from BFS assuming that the order of the vertex's in the adjacency list is the order BFS follows but can't seem to think of a counter-example that violates this statement.

Edit: I am not asking how to find the other shortest-tree paths, but an example that shows that there are OTHER shortest-tree paths that are not found by BFS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding all the shortest paths between two nodes in unweighted undirected graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144071/finding-all-the-shortest-paths-between-two-nodes-in-unweighted-undirected-graph)

Answer (score 0):

Confirm your graph is unweighted and undirected ?