# What is the best way to find shortest path between every pair of node in an undirected and unweighted graph?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm

I know about floyd-warshall and johnson algorithm but they are for directed and weighted graph. I want to find shortest path between every pair of nodes in an undirected and unweighted graph.

Can someone please help me with at-least a pseudo code. I'm not a very good algorithmic creator and understand things slowly. Can anyone help me in any way. I've already gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144071/finding-all-the-shortest-paths-between-two-nodes-in-unweighted-undirected-graph) question but understood little. Also that question is about all shortest path between two nodes and **my question is about shortest distance between every pair of nodes.**

Please help!

Comment: "Unable to understand anything" is a bit broad. It's going to be hard to explain the concept much better than Templatetypedef did, so any help you can give us in narrowing down what's giving you grief makes it easier to focus in on the problem spots and give you assistance that's likely to be more useful to you.

Comment: I edited it. Also I understand BFS and DFS clearly, maybe I wrote too much.

Comment: Floyd-warshall is not for "directed and weighted" graphs. Unweighted = each edge has the same cost (1). Undirected = each edge can be considered as two directed edges, its adjacency matrix is symmetric as such.

Comment: You want to know the shortest distance required to visit each node at least once?

Comment: @JohnFilleau yes and I also intend to do some work during calculation but that's upto me. I just want to know how can i achieve that?

Comment: Templaytetypedef happens to be online right now. With luck they will see this question and respond.

Comment: Starting from node 1, perform a breadth-first traversal of the graph. Continue until all nodes have been reached, noting the distance at which each node is discovered. Repeat for nodes 2..n.