# BFS for finding ALL shortest paths in a grid?

Tags: python, search, breadth-first-search

I am trying to implement BFS to find ALL shortest paths in a grid. Note that this means not one, not two, but all.
Let's take a graph of 9 nodes for example. The connections are undirected, and the nodes are placed in nodes of a grid-like format, like below:
0 1 2 
3 4 5 
6 7 8

Each number denotes a node's placement, and there are links between all nodes either directly above, below, to the left, or to the right of each other.
This means that 0 is connected to 1 and 3, while 4 is connected to 1, 3, 5, and 7, and so on.

I am trying to get ALL the shortest paths from 0 to 8, which would mean 6 paths in total. When I implemented the traditional BFS algorithm, I noticed that I was missing a few paths because of the manner in which the code places nodes into the set of seen nodes.

For example, after visiting 1 and 3 from 0, the code moved on to 0 - 1 - 2 and 0 - 1 - 4, after which it only looked at 0 - 3 - 6 and not 0 - 3 - 4 because 4 had already been parsed through with node 1.

Is there a way to get around this through BFS? Or should I be using a different searching algorithm? Thank you in advance.

Comment: We can only possibly diagnose problems in code that is actually shown to us. Please read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: You might find [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144071/finding-all-the-shortest-paths-between-two-nodes-in-unweighted-undirected-graph?rq=1) relevant.